# Spring Framework: findBy throws Illegal Argument Exception

Tags: java, spring, persistence, spring-data-jpa

This is my Entity Class.

```
@Entity
public class Profile {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long profileId;

@Transient
private String name;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Map<String, String> trNames;     //Key: LanguageCode, Value: translated text
...
}
```

ProfileRepository Class

```
public interface ProfileRepository extends JpaRepository<Profile, Long> {

//This method should go through the Map Collection and return a profile whose name matches the given parameter value.
Profile findByTrNames(String code, String name);

}
```

I created a JUnit Test Class to test this method.
This line of code

```
Profile found = repository.findByTrNames("en", "Interview IT");
```

throws an exception.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [en] did not match expected type [java.util.Map]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [en] did not match expected type [java.util.Map]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:301)
    at etc..
```

Could anyone please help me?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
@Query("select p from Profile p where p.trNames[?1] = ?2")
Profile findByTrNames(String code, String name);
```

**UPDATE**

JIRA ticket is created to support this feature: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-643

Comment: great.. It does indeed. :)
Could you please perhaps explain why it threw an exception? Why did it expect a type of java.util.Map?

Comment: `spring-data` constructs the query based on your declared method name which is `findByTrNames`. Since `trNames` is of type `Map`, it expects the parameter to be also a `Map`. I agree it could be a little smarter when it comes to `Map` fields in entities, since they are somewhat specific and it makes sense that two params in the method could be interpreted as key and value.

Comment: @Pedrag - Any chance you open a ticket in the JIRA for improved Map binding? I am sure we can sketch something out.

Comment: @OliverGierke Thanks for the suggestion, I've opened a ticket for this, updated my answer with issue reference